# Get position of image on the page

Tags: ms-word, office-js, openxml

Is there a way to get the X/Y position of an inline picture relative to page bounds? I'm open to OOXML solutions too as the API doesn't seem to have anything for this.

I have managed to figure out the OOXML section that appears to have this information (it is `<a:xfrm>` node), but the X/Y values in this node appear are 0/0 even when the image is not in the top-left corner of the page. In fact, the value is 0/0 for all images in the page, so I assume it is relative to paragraph or something.

Comment: Which app are you working with? Word, Onenote, Powerpoint?

Comment: @RickKirkham Sorry for the omission. It's Word.